# Synchronized block in stateless EJB

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.1, synchronized, stateless

Is it okay to have a synchronized block in a stateless EJB in EJB 3.1?

The synchronized block is for renewing a connection on connection errors.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you make a request. the Container provides you with a new instance of the Bean, or an existing instance from the bean pool. you work with the bean, release it, and then it goes back into the EJB Pool. having said that, I don't believe it's necessary to have the method synchronized, as there won't ever occur a time when two threads are using the same EJB instance.

If you want to work with Singleton Beans, then look into the `@LockRead` and `@LockWrite` annotations.
This [tutorial](http://www.jbesolutions.com/blog/?p=17) is quite helpful.